Classification of signature of a bilinear form restricted to a plane.
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{2,2} = (\mathbb R^{4}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$$
Consider $AdS^3$ be the set $$AdS^3 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid b(x,x) = -1\}$$
I want to classify the geodesics of $AdS^3$. Thanks to this answer, we have already classified the casual structure of geodesics.
In PhD Thesis, (chapter 1, first page), it is written that the geodesics are obtained by intersecting planes through the origin with $AdS^3$. Let $\Pi$  be the plane through the origin.  Then $AdS^3 \cap \Pi$  has negative index either $1$ or $2$, otherwise the intersection would be empty. Consider  the restriction $b|_\Pi$, now in the thesis, it is written that signature of the restriction to the plane has the following cases:

$b|_\Pi$ has signature $(1,1)$.
$b|_\Pi$ is degenerate with $AdS^3 \cap \Pi$ non-empty.
$b|_\Pi$ has signature $(0,2)$

Can anyone please help me why there are above said three cases? Cases $1$ and $3$ are clear to me because the intersection  $AdS^3 \cap \Pi$ has negative index either $1$ or $2$. Why there is case $3$?

Do not delete and repost questions. Edit them instead.

I'm going to ask the same question I did last time, which you didn't answer: what is your understanding of signature? How do you know your $b$ has signature $(2,2)$? In particular, what does it mean for $b|_\Pi$ to be degenerate, i.e. what would you need in order to construct such a plane $\Pi$?

@NicholasTodoroff Sorry, I deleted because my question was wrong there and was out of context too.  Let $b$ be a symmetric bilinear form on real real vector space. Then there is a basis  for which $b$ have the diagonal matrix representation. Let $n^+$  and $n^-$ are  positive and negative index, i.e. positive and negative eigenvalues. Moreover,  $n^+$  and $n^-$ are invariant under any diagonal representation by the law of inertia.. So, we take the standard basis and  write the diagonal matrix of $b$ accordingly.

@NicholasTodoroff I know that nondegenerate bilinear form means rank of the matrix of the bilinear form is full rank, i.e. $4$ in this case. $b|_\Pi$ is degenerate means rank of the matrix of the bilinear form is less than $2$ with dimension of null space is $1$. Am I right?

Following up on your comments:
You're not wrong, but talking about the rank of $b|_\Pi$ is not very helpful here. It seems what you're missing is the full picture for the law of inertia. There are not just positive and negative indices, there is a zero index: the number of zeros along the diagonal is also an invariant, and this quantifies the degeneracy of the form. A symmetric bilinear form is degenerate if and only if, when viewed in a basis that makes it diagonal, there is at least one zero on the diagonal.
I think it also helps to change language. It's not just "a" basis that makes the form diagonal, we give such a basis a special name: an orthogonal basis. So a less matrix-centric way to state the law of inertia is as follows:

For any symmetric bilinear form $b$ there exists an orthogonal basis, and further more there exists fixed integers $n_+, n_-, n_0$ such that every orthogonal basis can be written in the form $e_1,\dotsc,e_{n_+},f_1,\dotsc,f_{n_-},r_1,\dotsc,r_{n_0}$ where
$$
  b(e_i, e_i) > 0,\quad b(f_i, f_i) < 0,\quad b(r_i, r_i) = 0,
$$
for all applicable $i$.

So proving a space has a particular signature is the same thing as finding an orthogonal basis for the space.
We want to show that there is a plane $\Pi$ which is degenerate. By the above, that means we are looking for a null vector $v$ and a vector $w$ orthogonal to it, since then we can define $\Pi = \mathrm{Span}\{v, w\}$ and know that $v,w$ is an orthogonal basis for $\Pi$ and—since $b(v,v)=0$—know that $b|_\Pi$ is degenerate.
That is, we are looking for a vector $v\ne 0$ such that $b(v,v) = 0$, and a vector $w\ne0$ such that $b(v,w) = 0$. Can you find two such vectors for the given $b$?
